# Drag and Drop using Visual Studio in Asp.net plus Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Is there any simple way , on how i can drag an drop without coding in visual studio, while using Bootstrap and Asp.net in Visual Studio .

Comment: Drag and drop for building a UI in a web environment is not a good idea. You're far better off learning HTML and CSS and maintaining tight control over the layout.

Comment: @mason thanks , but is it possible for it however much its not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop functionality can be implemented in HTML5 compliant browsers, it's important that you're aware of this.So if you have users who are using old browsers this functionality may not work.

Here's a simple example which let's user drag the red `<div>` and drop it in one of two destination `<div>` elements:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function dragStart(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
            e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.getAttribute("id"));
        }
        function dragOver(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        function drop(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #dropBox1,#dropBox2 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 5px dashed gray;
            background: lightyellow;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px 0;
            color: orange;
        }

        #dragA {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dropBox1" ondragover="dragOver(event);" ondrop="drop(event);">
        <!--Dropped div can be inserted here-->
    </div>
    <div id="dropBox2" ondragover="dragOver(event);" ondrop="drop(event);">
        <!--Dropped div can be inserted here-->
    </div>
    <div id="dragA" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event);">
    </div>
</body>
```